# Loading the Trello client library with RequireJs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, trello

I'm trying to load the Trello client.js library with RequireJs.

Here is my require.config:

```
require.config({
paths: {
    'jquery': '../lib/jquery-3.3.1.min',
    'trello': 'https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=7881&token=6985',
    'vue': '../lib/vue.min',
    'popper': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min',
    'bootstrap': 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min'

},
shim: {
    trello: {
       deps: ['jquery'],
       exports: 'trello'
    },
    vue: {
        exports: 'Vue'
    },
    bootstrap: {
        deps: ['jquery','popper']
    }
}
});
```

Here is where I am loading it:

```
define(['trello', 'vue'], function(Trello, Vue) {

    Trello.post(/*some irrelevant info */);

}
```

Looking at the sources in the inspector, I can see that the source for client.js is pulled down. However I continually get the error 
`app.js:81 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why it `exports: 'trello'` and not `exports: 'Trello'`?

Comment: Basically, I see different cases throughout the usages. I think you should level all to the same character case